# Untaring a file in nodeJS child process throws exception

Tags: node.js, tar, gzip

I have a file `bundle.tar.gz` which I am trying to untar. The command `tar xvfz bundle.tar.gz` works on terminal.

However it fails when executed via node child process like so:

```
child_process.exec(`tar xvfz bundle.tar.gz && bash file.sh`,
    { cwd: path }, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (err && err.code !== 0) {
            deferred.reject({message: err.message});
        } else {
            deferred.resolve('COMPLETED');
        }
    }
);
```

The error I'm getting:
`message"=>"Command failed: /bin/sh -c tar xvfz bundle.tar.gz && bash file.sh ngzip: stdin: unexpected end of file\ntar: Unexpected EOF in archive\ntar: Unexpected EOF in archive\ntar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now\n`

I dont have a clue why this is not happening :(